# Does Ubercart have an external API?

Tags: ubercart

Does [Ubercart](https://drupal.org/project/ubercart) have an external API that a 3rd party site could query? Specifically from a fulfillment point of view? We need to be able to query the system for items to ship, then update the order's status and set a tracking number after the item shipped. All this is done on a completely different server/company, so needs to be done via a publicly exposed API (like a REST or SOAP service). Does Ubercart do something like this?

Comment: There are a couple of solutions for Drupal 6 ([Bee Colony](https://drupal.org/project/bee_colony), [UC Services](https://drupal.org/project/uc_services)), but I've never come across anything for Drupal 7. Focus has somewhat shifted to Drupal Commerce for 7. You could always implement your own [services](https://drupal.org/project/services)

Comment: Is there such a thing for Drupal Commerce? I searched and couldn't find anything...

Comment: [But of course](https://drupal.org/project/commerce_services) :)

Answer (score 0):

Ubercart does have an API (see http://www.ubercart.org/docs/api and http://api.ubercart.me/ ), but I don't see general REST or SOAP support related to fulfillment.

Some options may include [miniRESTapi](http://www.ubercart.org/project/miniRESTapi) or as noted [UCServices](https://drupal.org/project/uc_services) and [Bee Colony](https://drupal.org/project/bee_colony/) for Drupal 6. There are some vendor-specific SOAP implementations for CyberSource, but I do not know how well-supported they are.